# Set all values within a group to 0 when any value in the group is 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to scan a table and reassign values within a group to 0 if any of the values in that group is 0.  I can't seem to figure out a solution to this by searching various combinations of `Group By`, `Partition`, and `Any`.

The data I am starting with looks like

```
CREATE TABLE #QP
(
    [Method] VARCHAR(1),
    [Station] VARCHAR(1),
    [Instrument] VARCHAR(20),
    [LastAnalysis] DATE,
    [DaysPassed] INT
)

INSERT INTO #QP
(Method, Station, Instrument, LastAnalysis, DaysPassed)
VALUES
('A', 1, 'Polaris', '2016-07-19', 21),
('B', 1, 'Polaris', '2016-08-04', 5),
('C', 1, 'Polaris', '2016-07-31', 9),
('A', 2, 'Polaris', '2016-07-31', 9),
('B', 2, 'Polaris', '2016-08-09', 0),
('C', 2, 'Polaris', '2016-07-23', 17),
('A', 3, 'Polaris', '2016-08-09', 0),
('B', 3, 'Polaris', '2016-07-27', 13),
('C', 3, 'Polaris', '2016-07-19', 21)
```

And I would like the result to appear as (line breaks included for ease of interpretation)

```
Method  Station Instrument  LastAnalysis    DaysPassed  Weight
A             1    Polaris    2016-07-19            21      21 
B             1    Polaris    2016-08-04            5        5
C             1    Polaris    2016-07-31            9        6

A             2    Polaris    2016-07-31            9        0
B             2    Polaris    2016-08-09            0        0
C             2    Polaris    2016-07-23            17       0

A             3    Polaris    2016-08-09            0        0
B             3    Polaris    2016-07-27            13       0
C             3    Polaris    2016-07-19            21       0
```

The closest I've gotten so far is to use

```
SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN 0 = ANY(SELECT DaysPassed FROM #QP) THEN 0 ELSE DaysPassed END AS [Weight]
FROM #QP 
WHERE Instrument = 'Polaris'
ORDER BY Station, Method
```

But this sets every value in the `Weight` column to 0, when the values in the `Station` group should remain as they are.

If this has an answer already, I'd love to know the right search terms to use to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that using the `min()` window function will work. Give it a try:

```
SELECT *,
       case when min(DaysPassed) over (partition by station) = 0 then 0 else DaysPassed end as [Weight]
FROM #QP 
WHERE Instrument = 'Polaris'
ORDER BY Station, Method
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
      ,Weight= Sign(min(DaysPassed) over (Partition By Station)) * DaysPassed
FROM #QP 
WHERE Instrument = 'Polaris'
ORDER BY Station, Method
```

Returns

```
Method  Station Instrument  LastAnalysis    DaysPassed  Weight
A       1       Polaris     2016-07-19      21          21
B       1       Polaris     2016-08-04      5           5
C       1       Polaris     2016-07-31      9           9
A       2       Polaris     2016-07-31      9           0
B       2       Polaris     2016-08-09      0           0
C       2       Polaris     2016-07-23      17          0
A       3       Polaris     2016-08-09      0           0
B       3       Polaris     2016-07-27      13          0
C       3       Polaris     2016-07-19      21          0
```